# Meteor, how to submit an array of forms

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor application where I want to describe a "site" and a number of "ios" (input/outputs) for each site.  The site is described by the first 3 fields and stored in a collection named sites.  The ios are entered below that, and are stored in a collection named ios.  The idea is each site may have an arbitrary number of ios.  I would like to be able to edit any field for the site or any of the ios, click save, and have everything saved at once.  Because the number of ios will be limited to say 5 or so by physical circumstances, I think this will be a better user experience than having a separate edit page for ios.  However, I can't figure out how to save the ios when the site form is saved.  How could this be implemented?

Here is an image of what the form looks like:
https://app.box.com/s/rqjj9lb49twcitwo7rmdy6k9ta0vuztv

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a structure like this:

```
<template name="form">
  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Some code like this will add your different elements to different collections:

```
Template.form.events({
  'submit form[name="form"]': function(e) {
    var foo, bar, fooInsert, barInsert;

    e.preventDefault();

    foo = $(e.target).find('[name="foo"]').val();
    bar = $(e.target).find('[name="bar"]').val();

    fooInsert = {
      thing: foo
    }

    barInsert = {
      thing: bar
    }

    fooInsert._id = Collection1.insert(fooInsert); // Insert foo into Collection1
    barInsert._id = Collection2.insert(barInsert); // Insert bar into a different collection, Collection2
  }
});
```

It would help if you did show some code you're working with so we can make our answers better :)